# How can I allocate different ID or class to my list item?

Tags: sencha-touch

First, I apologize for my poor English.

I am trying to build a list where each item has a different ID or class, because I want to control which items are displayed (hidden or visible).

Can anyone help?

I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
    }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   model: 'Contact',
   sorters: 'lastName',
   data: [
       { firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'  },
       { firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'  },
       { firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer' },
       { firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'   },
       { firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'  },
       { firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'  },
       { firstName: 'Jacky',   lastName: 'Nguyen'  },
       { firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'   },
       { firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'},
       { firstName: 'Nigel',   lastName: 'White'   },
       { firstName: 'Don',     lastName: 'Griffin' },
       { firstName: 'Nico',    lastName: 'Ferrero' },
       { firstName: 'Nicolas', lastName: 'Belmonte'},
       { firstName: 'Jason',   lastName: 'Johnston'}
   ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.List', {
   fullscreen: true,
   itemTpl: '<div class="contact custom_class_{firstName}">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div>',
   store: store
});
```

by using above code you can add custom css classes to every item in list view, just specify custom_class_{uniqueid of model} for every node and then you can access it using `Ext.DomQuery.select('div{class=contact custom_class_{firstName}}');` and then you traverse the DOM to get the parent element which you can use it to hide list item

```
var div = Ext.DomQuery.select('div{class=contact custom_class_{firstName}}');
var listItem = div.up().up();
```