# How to add css for active item of a list in Sencha touch 2.2.1

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I am using list in sencha touch 2.2.1. And I have to add css only on active item of that list. I try following:

```
listItems.getActiveItem().addCls('gigaspace');
```

But it add that 'gigaspace' class to whole list and not to active item.

So, how can I add css for active item of a list.

Comment: you want apply gigaspace css class to the list item which is taped by user.. am i right ?

Comment: what are the style you want apply for active item ?.. if you just want to change the active item colour. then you can simply use $list-active-color sass variable to change.

Answer (score 0):

U should get the selected list item and then apply the class to it...  [How can I allocate different ID or class to my list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972803/how-can-i-allocate-different-id-or-class-to-my-list-item)